# Getting "No such Module" error when trying to run project

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods

I had a developer create an app for me and when they sent me the code, when I run it in xcode I get "No such module" error message each time. I have read through all the solutions here, have cleaned it, and nothing fixes this. I even checked the pod folder and everything looks good, below is the text of the pod file. I have read that you can update the pods, but I am still learning and do not know where to type "update pods"" to do this.

DBImageColorPicker is the module I keep getting the module error with.

target 'WallpaperBoard' do
use_frameworks!

```
pod 'IQKeyboardManagerSwift'
pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK'
pod 'DBImageColorPicker'
pod 'SSUIViewMiniMe'
```

end

Comment: Go to your project folder in a terminal and type that command. lhttps://cocoapods.org/

Comment: How do you open a terminal? I am new to using a Mac computer

Comment: Press the command (⌘) + Space bar, the spotlight search will come, type "Terminal" and press enter or open your "Launchpad" and search for terminal

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go and check out the cocoapods [documentation](https://cocoapods.org/).

First make sure that you are opening the project.xcworkspace and not the project.xcodeproj

Then:

1) Open terminal

2) Type in `sudo gem install cocoapods` and click ENTER, this is to install cocoapods on your macbook.

3) Navigate to the director where the project is stored.  (where you see the Podfile)

4) Type in `pod install`

Comment: Does it matter if I am doing it on a virtual machine? I am using macincloud.